# Nested arrays - tracking position of objects within array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a kanban/trello SPA as a personal project. A "Board" has many "Lists". A "List" contains many "Items" and an Item belongs to one "List". Extending trello's list functionality, items can also be Grouped within the list.

**What is the best approach for designing for these use cases?:**

The user can manually reorder items on their board - between lists, within the list, in and out of groups across lists too. 2 single Items can also be combined to create a new group with the 2 items in that new group.

**Approach 1:** 
All Items keep a ref to the parent List. I do some rendering on the frontend to group the items appropriately where obj1.groupid == obj2.groupid.

I start with a list of Items, filter for items not in a group, then render these on an individual card in the view. I then reduce the remaining array to group items by groupId. These grouped items then render on a "group" card in the view. I think this is the right approach by decoupling the models from the view.

Simplified output I wrote:

```js
var cards = [];

class List {
  constructor(items){
    this.items = items
  }
}

class Item {
  constructor(title, id,pos) {
    this.title = title;
    this.id = id;
    this.pos = pos;
  }
}

var list = new List([
  new Item("Football",),
  new Item("Rugby"),
  new Item("Cricket",1),
  new Item("Hockey",2),
  new Item("Cycling"),
  new Item("Swimming",1),
  new Item("Wrestling",2),
  new Item("Diving",2),
  new Item("Cricket",2),
  new Item("Running")
]);

for (var p = 0; p < list.items.length;p++){
  list.items[p].pos = p;
}

//create an array of items with a group id
var filteredList = list.items.filter(function(item){
    return item.id != null;
});

//create an array of items without a group id
var singleItems = list.items.filter(function(item){
  return item.id == null;
})

//move single items to the cards array first
for (var k = 0; k < singleItems.length; k++){
  cards.push(singleItems[k]);
}

//group remaining items by key:id
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
var arraylist = groupBy(filteredList,'id');

//get the remapped array
var results = Object.keys(arraylist).map(function(key) {
  return [Number(key), arraylist[key]];
});

//push the new groups to the cards array
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
  cards.push(results[i]);
};

//format and display the cards array at item level
for (var c = 0; c < cards.length; c++){
  if (cards[c].length > 1){
    console.log('Card '+[c]+':')
    for (var l = 0; l < cards[c][1].length; l++){
      console.log('--> '+ [l] + ' ' + cards[c][1][l].title);
    }
  } else {
      console.log('Card '+[c]+':');
      console.log('-->'+ [l] + ' ' +cards[c].title);
  }
}
```

**Problem:** How would you keep track of the position (index in list) of the cards in the view so that the order can be saved? Groups and Items exist in separate DB tables so seems not to make sense to try and keep track this way, but how to keep track on the Item or Group level?

**Edited to add example of confusion**
The cards are rendered to reflect the pos of the Item object but how do I handle a card rending a "group" of items where each item has a pos but the user has elected to position the group card differently, like below. What I think I actually want control over is the the position of the card?

```html
Card 0: pos 1
--> Football pos 1
Card 1: pos 2
--> Rugby pos 2
Card 2: pos 3
--> 0 Cricket pos 4
--> 1 Swimming pos 6
"Card 5:"pos 4
--> 0 Hockey pos 9
--> 1 Wrestling pos 8
--> 2 Diving pos 5
--> 3 Cricket pos 7
```

**Approach 2**
So instead a List could have many Groups. A Group can have many Items. Groups with only 1 Item render on a single card in the view. Groups with multiple Items render on a group card in the view.

**Problem:**It's easier to track the positioning in this method because pos is tracked through Group objects only. I see complication in moving items between groups though; items, lists and groups become more closely coupled this way no? Every new Item requires a new Group, adding an Item from a Group with a single Item to an existing Group requires either deleting the original Group or storing empty Groups.items = 0 in the DB which doesn't seem smart/useful.

Appreciate any advice

Comment: It's not really clear what question your asking.  But your item class has `pos` field, so one would assume your going to use this to store it's position.  That seems logical and the way I would do it, and indeed if you remove an item from a group and it no longer has an items associated with it, it then makes sense to tidy this up too.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I've added an example the issue I ran into when I tried approach 1 - how to track the position of cards that were grouped into one card in the view - would you recommend to set pos to all equal within the group?

Comment: I think your want 2 positions, one for your card(group) and one for your item.  Doing everything via Item is just making things harder.  Your groups & items are in separate tables too.  When you re-order a group you only then need to re-number the groups, if you reorder an Item, only the positions in the group will need re-numbering.  If you move items between groups, you would re-number the 2 effected groups. etc.